# Postgres SQL Case Join When not Stopping at First Case Match

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, case

I'm trying a Case Join using Postgres SQL where I want the search to stop after the first case that matches

```
select *

from 
table1 a

left join table2 b
on a.cond1 = b.cond1
    and case when a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3
                 then 1
             when a.cond4 = b.cond4
                 then 1 
             else 0
        end = 1
```

The intent is if cond2 and cond3 match to stop at that and just use rows from table2 which match othwerwise try matching on cond4. However the result is keeping rows that meet both criteria. Is there a mistake in my SQL query?

Sample Example:

```
table1
id, cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 1, 0, 1, 1
3, 0, 1, 1, 0
4, 1, 1, 0, 0

table2
cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, tag
1, 1, 1, 1, apple
1, 1, 0, 1, banana
```

result

```
id, tag
1, apple
2, banana
3, null
4, null
```

but i'm getting in additional
1, banana

Comment: Please add sample sample data and expected output.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` expressions in the `ON` clause.

Comment: @jarlh could you elaborate how it would be done in this example? Thanks!

Comment: Your query is doing just what you asked it to do. You need to use "join" (or inner join) instead of "left join" (short for "left outer join").

Comment: @belayer i'm getting 1, apple and 1, banana in the result but i only want 1, apple this is regardless of whether its an inner or left join

Comment: Why does banana doesn't fit to the first record?

Comment: Banana does fit by the condition "a.cond4 = b.cond4".  Rows 3,4 in results come from left join. Rereading your title indicates you expect processing to stop after 1 match. **It doesn't work that way** - all matches are returned. If you want to short circuit that you need to include sort and limit clauses.

Comment: @Belayer ok I get your explanation that the current query may not address the intent, could you elaborate on what the correct query should or could be? Thanks

Comment: @S-Man the intent is to only match records from table2 that meet criteria1 first and only if there aren't any to match based on criteria2 so since apple meets the first criteria, just keep that row / join

Answer (score 0):

you can try with CTE

```
with cte as(
select count(case when a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3 then 1 else 0 end) 
checkcondition1, 
   count(case when a.cond4=b.cond4 then 1 else 0 end) checkcondition2 
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.cond1 = b.cond1
)
select a.id, b.tag
from table1 a
left join table2 b
 on a.cond1 = b.cond1
and case when (select count(*) from cte where checkcondition1>0)>0 and a.cond2 = 
b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3
             then 1
         when (select count(*) from cte where checkcondition1=0 and 
checkcondition1>0)>0 and a.cond4=b.cond4
             then 1
         else 0
    end = 1
```

Comment: That matches banana to 4, not 2.  I'm still trying to understand why banana shouldn't match 1.  Is it because 1 has already been matched by apple?  I.e. The matches are supposed to be exclusive?

Comment: @AndyN yes the intent is if there are matches by the first criteria i.e. cond2 and cond3 then use that otherwise check for the second criteria i.e. cond4 instead

Comment: @AndyN, what is the expected result? the above query gives the result what is asked in the question

Comment: @user2392965, is this answered your question?

Comment: @KrishnaMohanVarma your query matches banana to ID:4.  The desired result is that it matches ID:2.

Comment: @AndyN, the result is matching with id 4 as expected (plz check below)

id, cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4
1,   1,        1,            1,      1
4,   1,        1,            0,      0

table2
cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4,  tag
1,             1,        1,        1,       apple
1,             1,        0,        1,       banana

Comment: @KrishnaMohanVarma i don't think id4 should match anything

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `lateral join`.  If there is only one matching row for each row in `a`:

```
select *
from table1 a left join lateral
     (select b.*
      from table2 b
      where a.cond1 = b.cond1 and
            (a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3 or
             a.cond4 = b.cond4
            )
      order by (a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3) desc
      limit 1 desc
     ) b
     on 1=1
```

Otherwise, you can phrase this as:

```
select *
from table1 a left join lateral
     (select b.*,
             rank() over (order by (a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3) desc) as seqnum
      from table2 b
      where a.cond1 = b.cond1 and
            (a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3 or
             a.cond4 = b.cond4
            )
     ) b
     on b.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you only want the 1st match found you can get that with:

```
select a.id,b.tag       
   from table1 a join table2 b on a.cond1 = b.cond1
  where (   (a.cond2 = b.cond2 and a.cond3 = b.cond3)
         or (a.cond4 = b.cond4)
        )
  order by a.id
  limit 1;
```

Just a (peev of mine) quick note on alias on tables. Pick an intuitive value. In this case t1 and t2 would be much more so than a and b.